# nginx - Why can't I access my error page directly?

Tags: nginx

I have a NodeJS application to which I forward requests using `proxy_pass`. When the NodeJS application is off, I want to display a custom error page. So I put a `5xx.html` file into `/var/www/some-folder/errors` and forward errors to it.

Now when I try to access `http://some.address.com` while the NodeJS server is off, the `502` error is raised and nginx correctly returns the `5xx.html` page.

Now according to `nginx.conf` (see below), I would assume that if I request `http://some.address.com/errors/5xx.html`, it gets forwarded through the `location ^~ /errors/` directive to `/var/www/some-folder` and then to `/errors/5xx.html`. But instead of getting the `5xx.html` page, I get the default nginx `404 Not Found` page.

Why can't I access the `5xx.html` page directly? Thank you.

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
   server_name some.address.com;

   location / {
       // some settings
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/;
   }

   location ^~ /errors/ {
       internal;
       root /var/www/some-folder;
   }

   error_page 502 503 504 505 /errors/5xx.html;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the page directly because you specified in your configuration to not allow such requests.

```
        internal;
```

See the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal):

> Specifies that a given location can only be used for internal requests. For external requests, the client error 404 (Not Found) is returned.

Comment: Oh God... That's what happens when you just copy something from somewhere without even knowing what it does. :) Thank you. I will accept your answer shortly.